# CREATE TABLE partially fails with PHP + PDO for Sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am creating tables in a SQLite database from a database dump made by Navicat.

Of the 3 CREATE TABLE queries I'm running, 2 fail, 1 works - so it's not a permission / connection / config issue.

Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "servers" (
"id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT(32) NOT NULL,
"type"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"host"  TEXT(128) NOT NULL,
"port"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"rcon_port"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "config" ("built"  INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE "users" (
"id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"username"  TEXT(32) NOT NULL,
"password"  TEXT(64) NOT NULL,
"salt"  TEXT(8) NOT NULL,
"last_login"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Trying to run this - only the `config` table is created.

I can execute this script with Navicat and the tables are created - is there something syntactically wrong about this?

Also no errors / exceptions are being thrown

The PHP:

`$path` and `$sql` are confirmed to be correct

```
$db_conn = 'sqlite:' . $path;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($db_conn);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->query(file_get_contents($sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Is PDO configured to throw exceptions on errors? `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` Also, please show us the PHP code used to run this query.

Comment: Yes it is - added the PHP code - also noticed another oddity. If I change the order of the statements - only the first gets executed. Thus each statement works on its own. Could there be something with the newlines or semicolons ?

Comment: It's possible, you should split the file's content by semicolon `;` and execute each separately. Try it.

Comment: Are all three `CREATE TABLE` statements in one file? Are you passing all through at once? (Not quite sure, but maybe PDO_SQLITE3 only permits single statements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try separating the file into individual queries and running those:

```
$db_conn = 'sqlite:' . $path;
$queries = file_get_contents($sql);

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($db_conn);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $queries = explode(";", $queries);
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $dbh->query($query);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Yup - this works - seems a bit odd that queries can only be run one at a time

Comment: You don't need to split the string into query-substrings. Just do $dbh->exec($queries) at the top and it will work fine ;-)

Comment: @LeandroF.Vaz: Well, that's what he did in the original question, and it didn't work for him.

Comment: Maybe he should replace query by exec. It really worked for me.

Comment: @LeandroF.Vaz: There's no difference between `query` and `exec` beside the fact that they return two different things.

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLite syntax diagram](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) does not include a comma after the list of columns and before the PRIMARY KEY declaration.  Since that is the most obvious difference between the tables that fail, try that first.

Comment: Tried - gave me : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error